# Multi user test with jest in parallel run

Tags: jestjs, end-to-end

I am trying to execute my test cases with multiple user creds. My current project uses JEST for API e-to-e testing where we are reading the credentials from .env file. What I am trying to achieve is, to use multiple user credentials at a time so that single account does not get block as it makes lot of API calls to server.

Is there any way where I can use credentials per worker thread in JEST parallel run?